# 'str' object has no attribute '__dict__'

Tags: python, json, serialization, dictionary

I want to serialize a dictionary to JSON in Python. I have this 'str' object has no attribute '**dict**' error. Here is my code...

```
from django.utils import simplejson

class Person(object):
    a = ""

person1 = Person()
person1.a = "111"

person2 = Person()
person2.a = "222"

list = {}
list["first"] = person1
list["second"] = person2

s = simplejson.dumps([p.__dict__ for p in list])
```

And the exception is;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/py-ide-online/2.352580383594527534/shell.py", line 380, in post
    exec(compiled_code, globals())
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Comment: Avoid using list as a variable name. By `list = {}` you've overwritten the built-in `list()` constructor.

Comment: `json.dumps(obj, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
s = simplejson.dumps([p.__dict__ for p in list.itervalues()])
```

Answer (score 6):

What do you think `[p.__dict__ for p in list]` does?

Since `list` is not a list, it's a dictionary, the `for p in list` iterates over the key values of the dictionary.  The keys are strings.

Never use names like `list` or `dict` for variables.

And never lie about a data type.  Your `list` variable is a dictionary.  Call it "person_dict` and you'll be happier.

Comment: A life saver. Me being a Python newbie, I couldn't believe such a simple thing wouldn't be working and this  "the for p in list iterates over the key values of the dictionary. The keys are strings" was the key. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a dictionary, not a list as your `list`, in order your code to work you should change it to a list e.g.

```
list = []
list.append(person1)
list.append(person2)
```